# Standard error returning blank string

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

Here is what I currently have:

```
let finalTask = Process()

var certArguments: [String]
certArguments = (["args"])

for i in CertificateInfo.intPaths {
    certArguments.append(i)
}

certArguments += (["-argflag", "args"])

finalTask.launchPath = "/usr/bin/openssl"
finalTask.arguments = certArguments

let errorPipe = Pipe()
finalTask.standardError = errorPipe
finalTask.launch()

let data = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
print("\(data) this is the data")
let error = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
print("\(error!) this is the output")


finalTask.waitUntilExit()
finalTask.terminate()
```

As of right now I am getting a return of bytes in the data debug line, but nothing is returning when I attempt to print out the output. I just get

```
382 bytes this is the data
unable to load private key
33962:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.6/src/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:330:
33962:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.6/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:428:
 this is the output
```

Anyone know why the output is not being properly displayed? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "unable to read ... " is your error output.

Comment: Are you saying the "unable to load private key...." is the output? If i comment out the debug print I still get those lines, its just not displaying in the text

Comment: I don't understand why you say your "output" is not properly displayed.  Your're getting 382 bytes back through the error pipe.  Those byes start out with `"unable to load private key\n33963:error:0606..."`  Now if I had to guess I would say there are probably escape characters in there as well because I'll bet the "33963" is part of a terminal escape sequence that's supposed to colorize the word "error" on an ANSI terminal.

Comment: @chrono: That is the output from stderr. Try `print(">>> \(error!) <<<")` and you should see it more clearly.